# How to design an Ad server with real time bidding feature

Tags: architecture, nosql, real-time, distributed

I'm currently working on building an ad server that would enable registered advertisers to bid for an impression on registered publishers' web sites. Advertisers will be charged by CPM model.

Some desirable attributes of the service are:

1. Around than 10 millisecond time to arrive at the ad to be served by completing the bidding process.
2. Support around 10k concurrent ad requests. This number may grow over time

From an architecture perspective, are there any general guidelines for such a service? 
Are there any caveats that need to be kept in mind?

To make it scalable, the service will have to be distributed. Which data store would fit the bill? I'm gravitating towards Cassandra.

Because advertisers will be charged on CPM basis, I think some kind of a counter will have to maintained to keep track of impressions. How can I ensure, given the highly concurrent and distributed nature of the application, that impression counts are not lost/wrong.

Similarly, how can it be ensured that the cost of the campaign never goes beyond the  budget allocated for the campaign(Example scenario I want to avoid: budget is $100, $99 spent, $1 remaining, two impression each costing 0.75$ are served concurrently, taking the cost the $100.5, when max budget was only $100)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
RK

Comment: You cannot simply ask the community to architect a solution for this. In case you need help, you should hire some experts...

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to read some papers, and you may refer to [m6d](http://m6d.com/) for help, it's a very famous dsp, and the technology in that company is very fantastic, you may find much useful information in its official website http://m6d.com , besides, it has also published many papers that related to online advertisement, you can search these in google scholar.

Hope helps!

Comment: any reference papers?